# Can the same Azure App Registration work for a PublicClientApplication as well as a ConfidentialClientApplication?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I have a Desktop application which uses Graph API.  It's working fine.  It's a Public Client app.

We have some new web services that will be accessing the same information as the Desktop App, only they are Web APIs.  Here, I would like to use the Confidential Client flow since I can safely store the secret in a config file on the server.

Do I create a new App Registration for the WEB API, or is there a way to make my already existing App Registration work for both Confidential and Public Clients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't mentioned which MSAL you are using, but in general you should create a new app registration unless there needs to be tight coupling between the two apps (for instance, in some cases of [OBO flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow)).

App registrations are free and [there are good reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63404450/6176452) for representing apps separately on Azure AD when they are actually, logically distinct (such as in your case).

Comment: Thanks for that.   Also, I didn't know there was more than one MSAL.  All I know is the "Microsoft Identity Platform".  I'll look into the others.

Comment: @ezG no worries! There's one for each platform, you can check them out here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-v2-libraries